# wondershaper on two interfaces

Tags: qos

I'm running Debian as a home router and server with DLNA, samba, and netatalk.

I've set up `wondershaper` for the external interface (not the outdated debian package but obtained and built from https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper.git) and have set it up in `/etc/systemd/wondershaper.conf`.

However, I notice when copying large files to samba that web and interactive traffic is slow -- presumably because the internal network is busy.

So: I guess I need to add `wondershaper` to the internal interface? Is this possible? The config file seems to support only one interface? Or is there a better way?